# How to get an instance of my object's parent

Tags: java, oop, parent-child

Is there a way in Java to get an instance of my object's parent class from that object?

ex.

```
public class Foo extends Bar {

     public Bar getBar(){
          // code to return an instance of Bar whose members have the same state as Foo's
     }

}
```

Comment: Can't you just `return this;`?

Comment: -1 for being unclear.  Also, if the intent was just to `return this;`, you wouldn't need a function for that.

Comment: @Erick Robertson: you didn't bother to read the code and the comment in the method.

Comment: Yes, I did.  The comment describes exactly what you should do.  Create and return and instance of Bar whose members have the same state.  I don't know how to do that, since you didn't include the definition of Bar or of Foo.

Comment: to be honest, the comment isn't clear whether a new instance is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this.  You can certainly write a method that will take a Foo and create a Bar that's been initialized with the relevant properties.

```
  public Bar getBar() {
       Bar bar = new Bar();
       bar.setPropOne(this.getPropOne());
       bar.setPropTwo(this.getPropTwo());
       return bar;
  }
```

On the other hand, what inheritance means is that a Foo *is a* Bar, so you could just do

```
 public Bar getBar() {
      return this;
   }
```

Comment: Yes, all you have to do is write the method how you want it to work.  If you just wanted it to `return this;`, then you should just do `Bar bar = foo;`  You don't need a method to do that.

Comment: It's not unreasonable to have a method that "casts" a Foo to a Bar as part of an API, say if you want certain clients to use your Foo only as if it were a Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short:

```
return this;
```

If you want to return a copy, then create a copy constructor on Bar that receives another Bar.

```
public Bar(Bar that) {
    this.a = that.a;
    this.b = that.b;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this this is an instance of bar, the simple thing is just "return this;"  but if you need a distinct object, perhaps you could implement java.lang.Clonable and "return this.clone();"

Answer (score 0):

If your class extends Bar, it is an instance of Bar itself.  So

```
public Bar getBar() {
  return (Bar) this;
}
```

should do it.
If you want a "different instance", you can try:

```
public Bar getBar() {
   return (Bar) this.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Foo **is-a** Bar, you can do this:

```
return this;
```

This will only return the parent instance of current object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection

```
    package com;

    class Bar {

        public void whoAreYou(){
            System.out.println("I'm Bar");
        }

    }

    public class Foo extends Bar{

        public void whoAreYou() {
            System.out.println("I'm Foo");
        }

        public Bar getBar() {
            try {
                return (Bar)this.getClass().getSuperclass().newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        public static void main() {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.whoAreYou();
            foo.getBar().whoAreYou();
        }
    }
```